# MapActivity is not showing list

Tags: android, listview

I am developing a scenario in which i have to show addresses of a nearest location in a listview which is on a **MapActivity**. But after running my code successfully the list will not appear on the **MapActivity**.

Here is my code:

```
public class GMapActivity extends com.google.android.maps.MapActivity implements OnClickListener{

    MapView _mapView;
    private static  int latitudeE6 = 37985339;
    private static  int longitudeE6 = 23716735;
    private GpsListener _gpsLister=new GpsListener();
    List<Overlay> overlayList;

    MapController controller;

    Button _cancelBtn;

    String returnAddress = "";

    ListView locationListView;
    ArrayList<String> locationAddressArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> locationAdapter;

    LocationListAdapter locationListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapscreen);

        _mapView=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        _mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        _cancelBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        _cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        locationListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.location_listview);
        /*locationAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(GMapActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, locationAddressArrayList);*/
        locationListAdapter=new LocationListAdapter(GMapActivity.this, locationAddressArrayList);
        locationAddressArrayList.add("RNT Marg");
        locationAddressArrayList.add("RNT Marg");
        locationAddressArrayList.add("RNT Marg");
        locationAddressArrayList.add("RNT Marg");
        locationAddressArrayList.add("RNT Marg");
        locationAddressArrayList.add("RNT Marg");
        locationListView.setAdapter(locationListAdapter);
        ///////////////START GPS/////////////////
        if(Constant.isGpsStarted==false){
            startGPS();
            latitudeE6=(int)Constant.latitudeValue;
            longitudeE6=(int)Constant.longitudeValue;
        }
        //GetAddress(Constant.latitudeValue, Constant.longitudeValue);
        /////////////////////////////////////////

        ////////////////////////////////GET NEAREST LOCATIONS/////////////////////////////
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) GMapActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Double l1 = location.getLatitude();
                Double l2 = location.getLongitude();
                //GetAddress(l1, l2);
            }
        };

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);  
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        List mapOverlays = _mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mapping);
        CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay =
                new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitudeE6, longitudeE6);
        OverlayItem overlayitem =
                new OverlayItem(point, ""+Constant.latitudeValue, ""+Constant.longitudeValue);

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

        MapController mapController = _mapView.getController();

        mapController.animateTo(point);
        mapController.setZoom(6);

        /*overlayList = _mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mapping);
        CustomPinPoint itemizedoverlay = new CustomPinPoint(drawable,this);


        double lat_coordinates[] ={27.700556,28.2642635,30.0018168,29.776669,29.4096819,29.4560611};
        double lng_coordinates[] ={85.3630,83.9735195,80.7382742,81.2518833,81.8115051,80.5403779};
        String place_name[] ={"kathmandu","Pokhara","Darchula","Bajhang","Bajura","Baitadi"};
        String place_info[] ={"Its an capital of Nepal","Its and tourist place of Nepal","Its one of the beautiful place in country side","CHD District Target:10 51,960, VDCs/Muncipalities reported:41/41","CHD District Target: 71,280, VDCs/Muncipalities reported: 47/47","CHD District Target:10 51,960, VDCs/Muncipalities reported:41/41","CHD District Target: 71,280, VDCs/Muncipalities reported: 7/7","CHD District Target:10 21,960, VDCs/Muncipalities reported:44/41","CHD District Target: 33,3123, VDCs/Muncipalities reported: 47/47"};

        try{
            for(int i=0; i<place_name.length; i++)
            {
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(lat_coordinates[i]*1E6),(int)(lng_coordinates[i]*1E6));
                OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, place_name[i], place_info[i]);
                itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            }
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            e.getStackTrace();

        }
        finally{
            overlayList.add(itemizedoverlay);
        }

        controller = _mapView.getController();
        controller.animateTo(new GeoPoint((int)(lat_coordinates[0]*1E6),(int)(lng_coordinates[0]*1E6)));
        controller.setZoom(8);*/
    }

    //START GPS
    public void startGPS(){
        Constant.isGpsStarted = true;
        _gpsLister.startGpsCallBack(GMapActivity.this);
        _gpsLister.stopGpsCallBack();
        _gpsLister.startGpsCallbackAgain(GMapActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.cancel_button:
            this.finish();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public void getNearestLocations(){

    }

    private void GetAddress(final Double lat, final Double lon) {
        Constant.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(GMapActivity.this,"", "Please wait...");
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(GMapActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
                List<Address> addresses = null;
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
                    if (!addresses.equals(null)) {
                        Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                        StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("\n");
                        for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {

                            locationAddressArrayList.add((String)returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i));

                            strReturnedAddress
                            .append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(
                                    "\n");
                        }
                        returnAddress = "Around: " + strReturnedAddress.toString();
                    } else {
                        returnAddress = "No Address returned!";
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    returnAddress = "Location: https://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&q=" + lat
                            + "," + lon;
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    returnAddress = lat + "," + lon;
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        locationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        locationListView.setAdapter(locationAdapter);
                        Constant.progressDialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
            };
        }.start();

        //  return returnAddress;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi can anyone answer this...?

Comment: Hi I have solve it myself.Actually it was a problem in my xml.

Answer (score 2):

This library is deprecated.

> Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API has been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012. This means that from March 18th, 2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this version. No new features will be added to Google Maps Android API v1. However, apps using v1 will continue to work on devices. Existing and new developers are encouraged to use [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).